# request undefined when extracting JWT

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js, nestjs, passport-jwt

I have followed this [guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#jwt-functionality) in an attempt to get JWT authentication working.

The only difference I have is that I keep JWT Token in HttpOnly cookie which means a custom extractor is required.

I found an [example](https://wanago.io/2020/05/25/api-nestjs-authenticating-users-bcrypt-passport-jwt-cookies/) of how to extract a Token from a cookie. So, the only difference is:

```
jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([(req: Request) => {
  return req?.cookies?.access_token
}])
```

Unfortunately, `req` is `undefined` for no apparent reason.

That's how my *auth.module.ts* looks like:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: 'qweqweqweqeqwe',
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '20s' }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthResolver,
    JwtAuthGuard,
    JwtStrategy
  ]
})
export class AuthModule { }
```

I have also created a strategy file *jwt.stragegy.ts*:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([(req: Request) => {
        return req?.cookies?.access_token
      }]),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrKey: 'qweqweqweqeqwe',
    })
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { userId: payload.sub, username: payload.username }
  }
}
```

*auth.guard.ts*:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}
```

**Could it be an error on passport.js library's side?** Like, @nestjs/passport fails to map arguments or something...

Comment: Are you certain `req` is what is `undefined`? Do you have a cookie-parser middleware installed?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel Absolutely. Also, when printing `arguments` — length is 0. And regarding cookie-parser — it's activated and in other places I am even able to access my cookie. `app.use(cookieParser())` that is.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, @AlexHerman did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

By following the docs, you should be able to get the request.

```js
import { ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario what was making the `payload.sub` undefined was the `login` function on `auth.service`.

Before *(not working)*:

```
async login(user: any) {
    const payload = { apiKey: user.apiKey, sub: user.userId };
    const token = this.jwtService.sign(payload);

    return `Access token=${token};\n HttpOnly;\n Path=/;\n Max- 
    Age=${this.configService.get('jwtConstants.expirationTime')}`;
}
```

After changes *(working)*:

```
async login(user: any) {
    const payload = { apiKey: user._doc.apiKey, sub: user._doc._id };
    const token = this.jwtService.sign(payload);

    return `Access token=${token};\n HttpOnly;\n Path=/;\n Max-Ag
    e=${this.configService.get('jwtConstants.expirationTime')}`;
}
```